QMediaPlayer QT6 How to get more accurate current file position?
I try to get current time with player->position(), but in the debug() I see not all frames, even I set timer update speed to 1 ms.
Debug output:
1828
1828
1828
1880
1880
1880
1933
1933
Seems that QMediaPlayer::positionChanged updates about 50ms at time.
How I can get more accurate frame counter?
Example code:
QMediaPlayer *player;
QTimer *timer;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWindow::updateTime);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QAudioOutput *audioOutput = new QAudioOutput(this);
    player->setAudioOutput(audioOutput);
    player->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("test.mp3"));
    player->play();
    timer->start(10);
}

void MainWindow::updateTime()
{
    qDebug() << player->position();
}


The implementation seems to be completely different for each platform, which one are you using?

I need a cross platform option in the future. But now I'm working in windows 10.
